# I have by mistake deleted my main photos,pictures etc

Tags: caching

We have deleted my favourite pictures and videos etc. So we have to do something and have to bring them back and we have clear the cache so please respond faster

Comment: This isn't  a programming question so it is off-topic here, [superuser](https://superuser.com/) is for general computing questions - but you need to provide more details - is this a PC or phone or tablet? What operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use? Windows, Linux, Android etc.? If did you remove files to recycle bin, you can bring them back by standard way in accordance with your OS.